# java swingworker doesnt work properly it publish but wont process

Tags: java, swing

I tried a simple code to scan all files from a directory with recursive  with `SwingWorker` but it seems the output wasn't so good
here is the code:

```java
public class BackupBackgroundProcess extends SwingWorker<Object, String> {
    public BackupBackgroundProcess() {
    }
    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> list) {
        System.out.println("PROCESSING FILE = "+list.get(0));
    }
    @Override
    protected void done() {
    }
    @Override
    protected FileStatus doInBackground() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("OK");
        File[] root;
        root = new File("/home/hilman/Pictures/err").listFiles();
        for (File file : root) {
            seekFiles(file, this);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void seekFiles(File f, SwingWorker thread) {
        if(f.isDirectory()){
            File[] listedFiles = f.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < listedFiles.length; i++) {
                File file = listedFiles[i];
                seekFiles(file,  thread);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(" PUBLISHING FILE "+f.getAbsolutePath());
            publish(f.getAbsolutePath());

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new BackupBackgroundProcess().execute();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Output expectation is

```
OK
 PUBLISHING FILE /home/hilman/Pictures/err/_1427612060421_1.userfile
 PUBLISHING FILE /home/hilman/Pictures/err/pic2.png
 PUBLISHING FILE /home/hilman/Pictures/err/pic1.png
 PUBLISHING FILE /home/hilman/Pictures/err/1.png
PROCESSING FILE = /home/hilman/Pictures/err/_1427612060421_1.userfile
PROCESSING FILE = /home/hilman/Pictures/err/pic2.png
PROCESSING FILE = /home/hilman/Pictures/err/pic1.png
PROCESSING FILE = /home/hilman/Pictures/err/1.ong
```

but it seems it only appear

```
OK
 PUBLISHING FILE /home/hilman/Pictures/err/_1427612060421_1.userfile
 PUBLISHING FILE /home/hilman/Pictures/err/pic2.png
 PUBLISHING FILE /home/hilman/Pictures/err/pic1.png
 PUBLISHING FILE /home/hilman/Pictures/err/1.png
PROCESSING FILE = /home/hilman/Pictures/err/_1427612060421_1.userfile
```

Does `SwingWorker` `doInBackground` method finish regardless if the process is not done? Why doesn't it work properly?

Comment: Yeah, this is probably because it's not getting enough time to between `publish` calls to process the "publish" queue. Trying adding something like `Thread.yield` or `Thread.sleep` after each call to `seek`

Comment: duh, can you tell me which method should i put Thread.sleep or Thread.yield?

Comment: *"...after each call to seek"* as an idea ;)

Comment: notice that the process method takes a list as arguement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, from my observations, when this occurs, it's because what's going on in the `doBackground` method is preventing what ever is processing the "publish queue" from being able to run.

Try adding a call to `Thread.yield` or `Thread.sleep` somewhere in the processing loop to allow the "publishing" thread time to process the "publish queue"

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class BackupBackgroundProcess extends SwingWorker<Object, String> {

    public BackupBackgroundProcess() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> list) {
        System.out.println("PROCESSING " + list.size() + " files");
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("OK");
        File[] root;
        root = new File("/home/hilman/Pictures/err").listFiles();
        for (File file : root) {
            seekFiles(file, this);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void seekFiles(File f, SwingWorker thread) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            File[] listedFiles = f.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < listedFiles.length; i++) {
                File file = listedFiles[i];
                seekFiles(file, thread);
            }
        } else {
            //          System.out.println(" PUBLISHING FILE " + f.getAbsolutePath());
            publish(f.getAbsolutePath());
            Thread.yield();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new BackupBackgroundProcess().execute();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Since you're doing a recursive call, I placed a call to `Thread.yield` after calling `publish`, but you could just as easily place it at the end of the `seek` method.

Remember, the process/publish process buffers results, so when `publish` is called, you might get a number of files, for example...

```
OK
PROCESSING 122 files
PROCESSING 127 files
PROCESSING 184 files
PROCESSING 144 files
PROCESSING 131 files
PROCESSING 147 files
PROCESSING 335 files
...
```

I tend to use `Thread.sleep(1)`, but I'd recommending testing with both a see what results you get...

Comment: @user965347: A similar issue is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26844713/230513).